# Change Groupby Transform Pandas code to Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to change this piece of Code to opertae using Pyspark.

```
df['Single'] = df.groupby(by=['Order', 'ID'])['Quantity'].transform(np.sum)-(df.Single)
```

```
df = df.withColumn("Single", df.groupby('Order', 'ID').transform(np.sum) - df.Single )
```

AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'transform'

Answer (score 0):

GroupedData object is like `groupBy()`.

You cannot use `transform()` on a GroupedData object without using an aggregate function (like `sum()`, `count()` ,etc.) on it.

Link to doc :  [GroupedData](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.html)